# Prefetching Generator(Sequence) in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, dataset, generator

I tried to implement a Generator with the tf.keras.utils.Sequence - Method following this Github-Page:
https://mahmoudyusof.github.io/facial-keypoint-detection/data-generator/

So my Generator has the form:

```
class Generator(tf.keras.utils.Sequence):

  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.on_epoch_end()

  def on_epoch_end(self):
    #shuffle indices for batches

  def __len__(self):

  def __getitem__(self, idx):    
  #returning the idxth batch of the shuffled dataset    
  return X, y
```

Unfortunately the training-processes of my model became very long with this generator so I wanted to prefetch it.

I tried

```
Train_Generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(Generator(Training_Files, batch_size=64, shuffle = True), output_types=(np.array, np.array))
```

to convert the generator to a type where prefetching works. I got the error message:

```
`generator` must be callable.
```

I know for this to work the generator musst support the Iter()-Protocol. But how can i implement it?
Or do you guys know other methods to improve the Performance of these kinds of generators?

Thanks ahead!!

Comment: Quick comment: you are probably better off rewriting your pipeline with `tf.data` functions. The guide [tf.data: Build TensorFlow input pipelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/data) could be helpful. Using `from_generator` has some drawbacks as it uses `tf.numpy_function` under the hood. If you want to implement the iter protocol, it's in the doc : [Iterator Types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#iterator-types)

Comment: thanks for the reply! the reason i use a generator is that i got my data saved as tfRecord-Files but i need to split the single protocolbuffers into multiple training sets. (I need  to split the saved timeseries) I couldnt find an elegant way to do this besides using a generator. Or is there a way to do this with a .map(parse)-functiion directly?  
thanks ahead. it would help me soo much

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to do like this:

```
Train_Generator = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(Generator, args=[Training_Files, 64, True], output_types=(np.array, np.array))
```

Comment: output_types will be deprecated